# pexpect on Windows, sending text to input-hidden field

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, passwords, pexpect

I'm trying to use python's `pexpect` library to interface with a command called `fei5kinit`, which creates a persistent authentication credential for a File Exchange Interface. On Windows and macOS, the process of simply running the command `fei5kinit` in the Command Prompt / Terminal looks like the following:

```
$ fei5kinit
Server group>>YOUR_GROUP
User name>>YOUR_USERNAME
Passcode>>YOUR_PASSCODE   <== the inputted passcode is invisible
$
```

With the right credentials, the command will finish with no additional ouput; the Command Prompt / Terminal will return to the standard input character, and the persistent authentication session will have been created. **Notably, the `Passcode>>` input field is hidden, and when you type, no characters appear there.**

On macOS, using python 3.11+, I have succeeded in capturing this entire process as follows:

```
# First, set up the fei5 command line tools (proprietary) and set the environment variable
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('fei5kinit')
child.expect('Server group>>')
child.sendline('YOUR_GROUP') # Example input
child.expect('User name>>') 
child.sendline('YOUR_USERNAME') # Example input
child.expect('Passcode>>')
child.sendline('YOUR_PASSWORD') # Example input
index = child.expect(pexpect.EOF, "Authentication Error") # Check for valid login
if index == 0:
    print('Authentication Complete')
else:
    print('Error')
# >>> Authentication Complete
```

After running this code, I am able to run other commands (like `fei5list` and `fei5get`) with a simple call to `subprocess.Popen`, and they behave as expected.

**However**, I am running into an issue when trying to do the same thing on Windows. Because `pexpect` is supported directly on Windows, I have replaced the line `child = pexpect.spawn('fei5kinit')` with `child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('fei5kinit')`. The rest of the code remains the same. From what I can tell, the code works just fine to send the `Server group` and `User name`, but fails when it hits the `Passcode` field.

I suspect that it might have to do with the fact that the `Passcode` field is hidden, and `PopenSpawn()` is not equivalent to `spawn()` in terms of ability to mimic user input, which might be required to interface with hidden fields. But that is just my theory. In addition to what I've described above, I have tried various approaches using `pywinpty`, `winpexpect`, and `pywinauto` to no avail. I have also tried using `subprocess` with no luck. The closest I have gotten is by spawning the `fei5kinit` command with `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn()`. I am running Windows 11.

I would appreciate any tips or ideas, including suggestions for a better formulation of my question. I have been stuck on this for weeks. Thank you!